# Azure Python SDK get zone info

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine

Anyone know how to get zone info using the Python SDK? I found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51828.azure-vms-availability-sets-and-availability-zones.aspx#Supported_Instances) technet post that shows you how to dump supported machine types by zone using powershell, and the Azure command line tools equivalent seems to be as follows:

```
user@server:~$ az vm list-skus -l southeastasia --zone | wc -l
   12350
user@server:~$ az vm list-skus -l southeastasia --zone | head -n 120 | grep family -A 18
    "family": "standardNVFamily",
    "kind": null,
    "locationInfo": [
      {
        "location": "southeastasia",
        "zoneDetails": [],
        "zones": [
          "3"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "locations": [
      "southeastasia"
    ],
    "name": "Standard_NV6",
    "resourceType": "virtualMachines",
    "restrictions": [],
    "size": "NV6",
    "tier": "Standard"
user@server:~$
```

But I haven't found the right SDK method yet after trawling through the docs for quite a while.

compute_client.virtual_machine_images.list_skus() does not return zone info, just image e.g.

```
{
  'additional_properties': {
    'properties': {
      'automaticOSUpgradeProperties': {
        'automaticOSUpgradeSupported': False
      }
    }
  },
  'id': '/Subscriptions/f03687b3-57b3-43c9-9734-6fb36e0de268/Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/southeastasia/Publishers/Debian/ArtifactTypes/VMImage/Offers/debian-10/Skus/10-backports',
  'name': '10-backports',
  'location': 'southeastasia',
  'tags': None
}
```

This is super easy using the AWS SDK:

```
boto3.client('ec2').describe_availability_zones()
```

Comment: Regarding the issue, please try to use the code ```results=compute_client.resource_skus.list()```. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_04_01.operations.resourceskusoperations?view=azure-python

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? It may help more people.

Comment: Hi Jim thanks for answering but the code doesn't quite work (NameError: name 'location' is not defined), did you mean this?

`if(result.resource_type=='virtualMachines' and result.locations[0].lower() == result.location_info[0].location.lower() ):`


result.location_info[0].location is always equal to result.locations[0] anyway so no need to filer.

I am also using
`len(result.location_info[0].zones) > 0`
to get redundant regions, and `result.location_info[0].location.lower().endswith('euap')`
to filter Early Updates Access Program images if anyone is interested.

Comment: I made a mistake. We need to provide a location manually. Sorry for that. For more details, please refer to my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, we can use the following code to get the zones. For more details, please refer to the [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/2146)

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute.models import ResourceSkuLocationInfo

AZURE_TENANT_ID= ''
AZURE_CLIENT_ID=''
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET='' 
AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=''

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=AZURE_CLIENT_ID,secret=AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,tenant=AZURE_TENANT_ID)
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials,AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
results=compute_client.resource_skus.list()
for result in results :
  
       if(result.resource_type=='virtualMachines' and result.locations[0].lower()==location.lower()):
          for r in result.location_info:
              for x in r.zones:
                  print('name'+result.name+' zone:' +x)
                  print('-----------------')
```

[image]
Regarding how to use the sdk, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_04_01.operations.resourceskusoperations?view=azure-python) and the [actricle](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/fc532b4dee320e7f20994d548f284729a0c66ae8/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/vm/custom.py#L817)

---

## Update

We need to provide a location in the code

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute.models import ResourceSkuLocationInfo
def _match_location(l, locations):
    return next((x for x in locations if x.lower() == l.lower()), None)
AZURE_TENANT_ID= 'e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb'
AZURE_CLIENT_ID='42e0d080-b1f3-40cf-8db6-c4c522d988c4'
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET='pMbSCzttaDh=-WE@g*32TiX5hBcBhY2@' 
AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID='e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68'
location='southeastasia' # the location you need to use
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=AZURE_CLIENT_ID,secret=AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,tenant=AZURE_TENANT_ID)
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials,AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
results=compute_client.resource_skus.list()

for result in results :
  
       if(result.resource_type=='virtualMachines' and result.locations[0].lower()==location.lower()):
          for r in result.location_info:
              for x in r.zones:
                  print('name'+result.name+' zone:' +x)
                  print('-----------------')
```